# notion-api invalid_client oauth integration

Tags: notion-api

I am creating a notion API integration with OAuth authentication.
I keep getting an **invalid_client** error when the user clicks allow access button and OAuth follow hits my callback URL. Also, **auth_token** is created in base64 format via **client_id:client_secret** which is provided in the integration console. **Code** is returned as query param when the OAuth process hits my callback URL.

What am I missing?

```js
const code = req.query.code;

const auth_token = Buffer.from(
    "my_oauth_client_id:my_oauth_client_secret" // provided in integration panel
).toString("base64");

await axios
    .post(
        "https://api.notion.com/v1/oauth/token", {
            code,
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            redirect_uri: "https://notion-fastlane-web-2hfaoof9v-oak93.vercel.app/api/notion/oauth/callback",
        }, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Basic ${auth_token}`,
            },
        }
    )
    .then(() => res.status(200).send("OK"))
    .catch((error) => {
        res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.data);
    });
};
```

Comment: is this still giving you a problem

Comment: yes, i do not know why @rawk

Comment: Is this the full Oauth flow?

Comment: I don't think the issue here is the POST, it's where you GET the authorization code. Are you successfully getting the code back?
```
//Get authorization code, then create body and headers for token exchange
app.get(access_token_path, ({query: {code}}, res) => {
  const body = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    code,
    "redirect_uri": `${callback_uri}`,
  };
  const options = {
    headers: {
    "Authorization": `Basic ${auth_token}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }```

Comment: Is your redirect_uri the same when you start the flow by opening /v1/oauth/authorize?

Answer (score 2):

I also found this part of the authorization process really confusing as a beginner.

When working on my integration, I found that Axios provides an "auth" param (https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) you can add to the request options where you can specify the Basic Authentication parameters, which are the *client id and secret* aka *username and password*, and it will base64 encode them for you and put them in the right format Notion specifies. You can check out the rest of the request config I used to see if there's anything else you're missing.

```
 {
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.notion.com/v1/oauth/token",
    auth: {
      username: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      password: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
    data: {
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      code: temp_code,
      redirect_uri: "https://example.com/oauth/redirect",
    },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, 
}
```

Also, I made a simplified diagram of the entire OAuth process with Notion if that would help: https://naomiperez.netlify.app/notion-oauth-flow/